# OpenGL in iOS: lines drawn are very not smooth

Tags: graphics, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am working on a graphic application in which the user draws lines.
The lines are not smooth. I see the problem especially when drawing the lines slowly.

What would be the correct way to smoothen the lines?

I read the following great article: http://www.merowing.info/2012/04/drawing-smooth-lines-with-cocos2d-ios-inspired-by-paper/

It fixed some of the problem, but not all of it. Still, when drawing lines slowly, they look jagged:

[image]

Comment: Could you include an illustration of your current result? "Not smooth" could indicate several issues. And perhaps include the relevant code, so we can see what you're doing.

Comment: I added a screenshot that shows how it looks.

Comment: And you're using the method from the article you linked? Because it seem to me you're just drawing segments straight down, and not connected as in the article. Showing us the code would help.

Comment: I can't share my code, unfortunately. However, i tried using both glDrawArrays with GL_LINE_STRIP and glDrawElements with GL_LINES

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is actually that you have ***too many*** sample points.

This is why the problem is exacerbated when the user inputs points slowly, rather than quickly. One possible solution is to use some sort of best-fitting line equation (e.g. [Least Squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares)) to reduce the number of points and simplify it to an approximation.

There are more sophisticated approaches to smoothing user input, but in this simple case all you really need to do is reduce the sample size.

Comment: If you draw an array of `GL_POINT` primitives at each of the sampled points in your line, you will see why my answer applies. When the user inputs points slowly, you generate more samples and the line is inherently less smooth as a result (after all, the more points you introduce the more it deviates from an ideal line). When they do it quickly, you have fewer sampled input points. In this case, you are approaching the problem incorrectly. I do not understand the down-vote with no explanation, that is rude.